# R or Matlab code for Multi-Barrier-Options (3 or more underlyings)

Tags: option-pricing, programming, exotics

I am looking for R or Matlab code examples of multi-barrier-options (or multi-barrier reverse convertibles) with at least 3 underlyings. Do you have such code or can you point me to a place where I can find it.

Comment: What kind of pricer are you looking for?

Comment: Ideally an R script which I can feed with the data required (strikes etc.) and which conducts the simulation exercise and delivers prices or coupons for the instruments. There is a Bloomberg function called OVSN which does the job, but I want to have my own pricer where I can add my assumptions as I like.

Comment: AFAIK there are no closed form solutions for this type option. So you will need some approximation scheme. I'm sure more than one exists, do you have any opinion on them?

Comment: Shooting to do zero work here, huh? There a bunch of pricing functions here:
http://www.volopta.com/index.html

Comment: i am aware that there are no closed form solutions. as i am not a derivatives geek, i am just looking whether there is code out there which i can adapt. also, i would be curious what model the traders use (or which is most common).

Comment: I think you're last sentence would make a good question, if you're content with just any random pricer Googling would be best I believe.